# Problem with the "Announcer" badge page...

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges

[image]
https://askubuntu.com/badges/57/announcer

As you can see in the above screenshot, if the question is too long, the information about the user who received the `Announcer` badge is cut off.

Answer (score 9):

Truncation of the post text with either an Ellipsis (...) in the middle or at the end to ensure proper rendering.

Alternatively moving the badge winner to the front of the post rather than the end should  alleviate this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed with the badge page redesign